# How to sort primary column with alphabet order then secondary column with numeric order?

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

Assuming there is a text file:

```
10  A   QAZ
5   A   EDC
14  B   RFV
3   A   WSX
7   B   TGB
```

I want to sort it with the second column as the main column with alphabet order and the first column as the secondary column with numeric order. The following is the expected result:

```
3   A   WSX
5   A   EDC
10  A   QAZ
7   B   TGB
14  B   RFV
```

I tried `sort -k 2,2 -k 1,1 a.txt -n` and `sort -k 2,2 -k 1,1 a.txt` but both give the wrong results. What should I solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
sort -b -k2,2 -k1,1n
```

The `-b` is essential, without it, the output is wrong, since `sort` wrongly determines the position of the second column. See `man sort`  (or [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort)) for details.

Also, check your `locale`. They can influence how `sort` works.

Comment: The second field specifier is unnecessary.  `sort -b -k2 -k1n` should work

Comment: The -b is what I was missing from my own (deleted) answer. It appears that `sort` treats the minimum amount of whitespace present between two fields as the separator, with any extra space in a given line assigned to the second field.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Not really. Check `echo $'3   A   WSX\n14  B   RFV\n2   A   ZZZ'`.

Comment: Looks like `-k2,2 -k1n` works, though. (Maybe someone can clarify what the default is if you specify only the first field with `-k`.)

Comment: @chepner: The linked man page says it: it's the end of the line. Once you start getting numbers in column 2, you might need k1,1, too.

Comment: Ah, should have read that. The man page I read was opaque and probably worded so as to be wrong: "start a key at POS1, end it at POS2 (origin 1)". The fact that columns 2 (and 3) are not numerical probably contribute to making `-k1` work.

Comment: @choroba: Great! This is exact what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sort -k1.5,1.8 -k1.1,1.4n file
```